# How to change encoding in Mail in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: email, macos, text, encoding

Normally I would open Mail.app, click **Message** → **Encoding** → **[One of the Cyrillic encodings]**. But since the upgrade I don't see text encoding option in Message menu.

How to change to use one of the Cyrillic encodings?

Comment: [This](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23472933#23472933) answer offers an alternative solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use either the default or utf-8?  You can check the default by doing view > message > raw source on something in your sent folder and checking the header for charset = .   Why Apple deleted this I can't imagine, very stupid of them.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're not [the only one](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24044177) with this problem.

I found a KB article on Apple's website that clearly specifies that **Message** > **Text Encoding** should be available in the Mavericks version of Mail:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14955

It says "Mavericks" in the title and is current as of Nov 6, 2013.

I've filed a bug report letting the OS X team know.

Comment: Hopefully the OS X team's reaction will not be to just change PH14955, which someone probably copied from an earlier version without realizing this aspect had changed. In my experience PH notes often contain such errors.

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, let's hope so. I do find it curious though if they chose that as a "solution" (Since it's apparently a big problem for some geographical regions). But then again; they did poke around Mail quite a bit during development of Mavericks in an unfortunate way. Which they're *still* trying to fix.

Comment: In theory it should not be problem, since all emails should contain correct charset headers and all modern email clients should correctly decode the charset headers used by Mail in sending various languages.  In practice of course this doesn't always happen.  I must admit though that I have seen a lot fewer complaints about this omission than I would have expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem.  Tried the thread from Alex comments ([here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23472933#23472933)), seems can solve my problem. But Apple should bring back the Text Encoding option.